# why the css of my django application only works in incognito mode?

Tags: css, django, static, styles

I don't know if it's happened to someone else, but I have a django application that only shows the styles created in css only when it's in incognito mode, when the browser is in normal mode you can't see the changes created in css.

what would cause the problem? and how can i fix it?

Comment: Have you also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73452608/17562044) answer?

Answer (score 2):

Try to clear your browser cache, I think that should help you.

```
Steps to clear cache and hard reload on chrome:
1. open the website
2. Inspect the page
3. Right-click on the refresh button near the URL bar
4. Click on 'Empty Cache and Hard Reload'
```

Answer (score 2):

It may be due to `caching`. The `incognito` mode is not cached and hence you can see the changes. One of the ways could be is to use `version` as a query param in your CSS URL to bluff the browser and ask them to fetch each time you change the number. Like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/css/style.css?version=1" />
```

you can change the number of version after each edit

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to Cache. Due to caching, you're seeing an old version of your styles (CSS).
In incognito mode, this is not a problem because Chrome uses a fresh cache when you start a session and removes that cache when you end the session.
**You can solve your problem by clearing your cache**.

OR

Disable cache in your browser.

[image: disable cache]

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes browsers cache your website. But in incognito mode, the browser doesn't cache your history and searches.
To remove your cache, follow these steps:

1. Right click and inspect
2. Hover over the reload button near the url box
3. Right click on reload button
4. Click on "Empty cache and hard reload"